# Using an OrderBy after GroupBy in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have a group of students, and I want to group them by their class level, like Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, Senior. And then I want to order them by GPA.

So if I just wanted to get the student with the best GPA, my potential result set would be something like:

```
Freshman - Name: James GPA : 3.9 
Sophomore - Name: Jessie GPA : 4.0
Junior - Name: Caitlyn GPA: 3.9
Senior - Name: Joshua GPA: 3.95
```

I've tried something like this:

```
var result = students.GroupBy(x => x.Level).OrderByDescending(x => x.GPA).Take(count).ToList();
```

but it always breaks and I don't quite know how to fix it. I've tried putting a Select between them and moving the OrderBy in the Select but I couldn't get it working either.

Comment: *but it always breaks and I don't quite know how to fix it.* Breaks how? If you're using NHibernate ... its LINQ provider is not very good.

Comment: most likely it doesn't compile because there is no GPA property on a group

Comment: I'm not quite sure why it breaks, to be honest. I will have it in a way that throws no errors, but the program crashes when I run it. And I am just using Visual Studio with the regular Linq using statement.

Comment: _And then I want to order them by GPA_
Do you want to order students within each group? Or order the groups by highest/lowest/average GPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna get the student who has the biggest GPA from each group you can use:

```
students.GroupBy(x => x.Level)
      .Select(g => g.First(x => x.GPA == g.Max(y => y.GPA)))
      .Take(count).ToList();
```

You can also use a third-party library method [`MaxBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c) to do that more efficiently

```
students.GroupBy(x => x.Level)
          .Select(g => g.MaxBy(x => x.GPA))
          .Take(count).ToList();
```

Comment: This does not give me the result I am looking for. It returns three Sophomores and a Senior with the lowest GPA.

Comment: you mean you wanna get the student that has higgest GPA from each group? it is hard to understand that from your question

Comment: Yes, that is what I am attempting to do. I'm sorry if my question was a bit off. I wasn't quite sure how to ask it without being overly complicated.